# About ECMs and considering Adjective Phrases as predicates

Tags: syntax, cases, generative-grammar

I'll just jump right to it.

I'm given the following sentence - "We remembered the scary dream", with the instructions to draw an X-Bar, and decide whether this is an ECM or a normal control type.

The thing is - it looks like a regular, simple sentence to me.
Trying, or rather, forcing the ECM tests with idiomas and expletive DP, I can reach the conclusion that this is, in fact, an ECM sentence.
But then it occured to me - if this is an ECM sentence, what's the inner predicate? Is it "scary"? Can "scary" even be considered a predicate? And how does this fit the ECM theory?

Comment: It fits the ECM theory any way ECM theorists care to stretch it. Like you said, it's just an ordinary sentence, without X-Bars, DPs, or any other superpowers. All the rest is ritualistic speculation about presupposed but non-existent non-terminal nodes -- what I call "angels and pinheads". The parse is [ˢ [ⁿᵖ _we_ ⁿᵖ] [ᵛᵖ _remembered_ [ⁿᵖ _the scary dream_ ⁿᵖ] ᵛᵖ] ˢ]. Standard SVO. Parsing _the scary dream_ is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: If you want a derivational analysis, you could start from _We remembered the dream which was scary_, get rid of _which was_ by Whiz-deletion, and then, since _scary_ is only one word, the Eleven-year-old Boy Rule applies to move it before _dream_. Though the semantics of _We_ remembering _the dream_ is gonna go all Wittgensteinian on you -- dreams are individual, but _we_ is plural. So an unusual, maybe metaphoric sense of some or all of _we, remember,_ or _dream_ is called for. Potentially also _scary,_ too. Oh, btw, yes; _scary_ can be considered a predicate. A predicate adjective, in fact.

Comment: In return, please tell me what _ECM_ stands for and what you understand about the phenomenon.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Well, I do have to come clean at first then - this was an excercise in Hebrew, which I translated to English. Gloss would be something like:
"zaxarnu et ha xalom ha mafxid
remember.1pl.pst det.dream det.scary"

Now, I'm still a bit unclear about using scary as predicate. Could you provide an example? Adjective predicates are so damn wierd at times.

ECM being the Exceptional Case Marking. In Generative Linguistics, we talk about "PRO" and "pro" as unheard\unvoiced anaphora or pronoun. 
This stands out especially in certain sentences such as "I like to run". (see next comment)

Comment: "I like to run" would be parsed as: I₁ like [PRO₁ to run]. (Site note: how did you manage to use superscript in comments?)
This would be a normal PRO usage with object-control type. The sentence "to run" has "-inflection" as it's nuclei.
Now, some nuclei hand out cases. Thus, the case filter is born. Inflectional sentences (+inflections) can give the nominative phrase. Verb nuclei can give the accusative case. Other nuclei (P, for example) just hand out the Oblique case.

So, without going too much in depth, trying to parse this:
"I heard David likes Anna", would result in something weird ->

Comment: I heard [David likes Anna]. David gets an accusative case from "heard", whilst actually being the topic of "David likes Anna". This is an example of ECM.

These might be really bad example, @jlawler, and I'm sorry. I'm having a hard time translating my thoughts into English at the moment. Hah.
But there are so many topics that were mandatory before we were taught ECM, I can't go about it in comments, really.


Also, we haven't covered many of the ideas\rules you wrote about. Whiz-deletion, Eleven-year-old Boy Rule, and Wittgensteinian. All new terms for me.

But thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, it's just an angels'n'pinheads account of [Equi and Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). Thank you. The tree always looks better with the decorations, of course, but they're so hard to handle because they don't exist. Though they're completely necessary in order to account for the other non-existent pieces required by the theory. Oh, and you won't be introduced to those topics if you're being taught ECM. They are haram to MITish theorists because they don't assume whatever Reb Chomsky currently assumes.

Comment: @Jlawler, very entertaining!